# Query for isolating process from tasks data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table of tasks in some processes:

```
ID  | PREV_ID | NEXT_ID | TASK_TS
----+---------+---------+--------------------
100 |         |   101   | 2013-01-10 10:22:00
101 |   100   |   102   | 2013-01-10 10:25:12
102 |   101   |         | 2013-01-10 10:27:00
103 |         |   104   | 2013-01-10 10:31:00
104 |   103   |         | 2013-01-10 10:35:00
105 |         |         | 2013-01-10 10:38:22
```

ID is the task ID, PREV_ID is ID of previous task in process chain and NEXT_ID is ID of next task in process chain, TASK_TS is timestamp when task (event) happened.

I need the query which will isolate processes from this table represented with starting task ID, calculate the number of tasks in process and duration of process (difference between last and first task in process task chain) in mins/hours/days (doesn't matter).

```
ID  |  TASKS | DURATION
----+--------+---------
100 |    3   |    5      <-- this process has 3 tasks and lasted 5 mins
103 |    2   |    4      <-- this process has 2 tasks and lasted 4 mins
105 |    1   |    0      <-- this process has only 1 task and lasted 0 mins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query to find the root id - i.e. the first task - for each chain:

```
select t.*, connect_by_root id as root_id
from t42 t
connect by id = prior next_id
start with prev_id is null;

        ID    PREV_ID    NEXT_ID TASK_TS                         ROOT_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------- ----------
       100                   101 10-JAN-13 10.22.00.000000000        100 
       101        100        102 10-JAN-13 10.25.12.000000000        100 
       102        101            10-JAN-13 10.27.00.000000000        100 
       103                   104 10-JAN-13 10.31.00.000000000        103 
       104        103            10-JAN-13 10.35.00.000000000        103 
       105                       10-JAN-13 10.38.22.000000000        105
```

This uses the [`connect_by_root` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators004.htm):

> `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` is a unary operator that is valid only in hierarchical queries. When you qualify a column with this operator, Oracle returns the column value using data from the root row. This operator extends the functionality of the `CONNECT BY [PRIOR]` condition of hierarchical queries.

So however many levels down the hierarchy a row is, you can still see which root it's related to. In this case the first three rows are all related to root ID 100, for example; that isn't obvious for ID 102 without traversing the hierarchy.

You can then use that hierarchical query as a subquery that groups based on the root ID:

```
select root_id as id, count(*) as tasks,
  max(task_ts) - min(task_ts) as duration
from (
  select t.*, connect_by_root id as root_id
  from t42 t
  connect by id = prior next_id
  start with prev_id is null
)
group by root_id
order by root_id;

        ID      TASKS DURATION  
---------- ---------- -----------
       100          3 0 0:5:0.0   
       103          2 0 0:4:0.0   
       105          1 0 0:0:0.0
```

The duration here is an interval (day to second) as I made the `task_ts` column a timestamp. If yours is actually a date then you'll see a fraction of a day instead. Either way you can convert that to the format you want.

[SQL Fiddle with timestamps](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42e50/2) or [with dates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f56cac/1).

Comment: Well done! You did it While I was typing same answer :-)

Comment: I don't need hierarcical query to find root, each row with PREV_ID IS NULL is root.

Comment: @sbrbot - you need the hierarchical query to find that the root of ID 102 is 100, via the `connect_by_root` operator. Otherwise how would you associate 102 with 100? The `start with prev_id is null` is identifying the root IDs, yes, but you need to know which of those applies to every non-root row, so you can do the grouping and aggregation.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for your answer and expertise in explaining the solutio, "connect_by_root" operator is something new to me.